# Spark sql dataframe drop all columns from alias table after join

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to join two dataframes with the same column names and compute some new values. after that i need to drop all columns of second table. The number of columns is huge. How can I do it in easier way? I tried to .drop("table2.*"),but this dont work.

Comment: even `.drop("table2.specificColumnName")` doesn't work; forget `.drop("table2.*")`.

Comment: Could someone explain why `drop("foo.column")` doesn't work?

Comment: not sure... it does work in principal... but when you have many columns, its not feasible. 
You can then do `.drop('table2.x1', 'table2.x2', 'table2.x3')`, but again, if you have a lot of columns this wont work. And you can't always just say `.drop('table2.*')` as you might want to keep some columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `select` with aliases:

```scala
df1.alias("df1")
  .join(df2.alias("df2"), Seq("someJoinColumn"))
  .select($"df1.*", $"someComputedColumn", ...)
```

reference with the parent `DataFrame`:

```scala
df1.join(df2, Seq("someJoinColumn")).select(df1("*"), $"someComputedColumn", ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of dropping, you can select all the necessary columns that you want hold for further operations something like below

```
val newDataFrame = joinedDataFrame.select($"col1", $"col4", $"col6")
```

Comment: Its not a case, if I have like 50 columns + 50 columns in second table. Can i select "table1.*" + names of new columns